# How can I write this menubar in jQuery, so the tabs stay in their hover state?

Tags: jquery, menu, hover, toggle

I've got a simple menubar, [seen here](http://www.bridgecitymedical.com/). My issue is that when you hover over the tabs, and the sub-menu slides down, and then you hover over the slide menu, the tab goes off of its hover state.

Here's my jQuery:

```
$('.js-tab').hover(function(){
    $(this).css('background-color', 'black').css('color', 'white').children('.js-icon').css('background-position', '0px -65px');
},function(){
    $(this).css('background-color', 'white').css('color', 'black').children('.js-icon').css('background-position', '0 0');
});

$('nav').hover(function(){
    $('.js-subitems').slideDown(150);
},function(){
    $('.js-subitems').slideUp(200);
});
```

.js-tab(s) are all the tabs. On hover, their css changes to invert the color, and select an inverted part of the sprite. 'nav' is the entire menu. Its size is dictated by the elements within it, it has no specific styling, I'm selecting it instead the tabs for the sub-menu so the sub-menu will stay up when you hover over it.

Here's my CSS:

```
.js-subitems {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    width: 539px;
    height: 170px;
    margin: 0 0 0 313px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.5);
    border-top: 0px solid transparent;
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    z-index: 7;
    padding: 15px;
    padding-top: 185px;
    color: white;
}

.js-icon{
    background-color:transparent;
    background-position:top left;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    position:absolute
}

.js-menu{
    float:left;
    width:570px;
    height: 340px;
    position:relative;
    margin-left:313px;
    border-left: 1px solid #CCC;
    z-index:10
}

.js-menu li{
    float:left;
    border-right:1px solid #CCC
}

.js-tab{
    background:#fff;
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;
    width:94px;
    height:170px;
    text-decoration:none;
    z-index:8
}

.js-tab h2{
    font-size:13px;
    font-weight:500;
    left:0;
    position:absolute;
    top:120px;
    width:97px;
    text-decoration:none
}
```

NOTE: Although the background color can be changed without use of javascript, I'm trying to keep all of it in the same place. I'll slim this down later, compression is not important at the moment.

**What I need**, is a to add some jQuery so that when you move your cursor from the tab onto that sub-menu, the tab you had moved from stays selected. *Then,* when you hover from that sub-menu, back onto a tab in the menubar, tat tab becomes selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think binding the hover event to only the li should work:

```
$('#js-menu li).hover(function(){
    $(this).find('.js-tab').css('background-color', 'black').css('color', 'white').children('.js-icon').css('background-position', '0px -65px');
    $(this).find('.js-subitems').slideDown(150);
},function(){
    $(this).find('.js-tab').css('background-color', 'white').css('color', 'black').children('.js-icon').css('background-position', '0 0');
    $(this).find('.js-subitems').slideUp(200);
});
```

That will trigger both changes that you need. However, I would also put each sub item list within the li as well, like this:

```
<li data-hovercolor="#fff">
    <a href="/" class="js-tab">
    <h2 data-type="mText" class="js-item">Home</h2>
    <span data-type="icon" class="js-icon js-icon-home"></span>
    </a>
    <div class="js-subitems">
        Testing the text.
    </div>
</li>
```

This way, since the sub items are part of the parent li, the parent li will keep the hover effect on when mousing over the sub items.

**EDIT:** After some discussion, a new solution was needed. I am pretty sure this should be working for what you need: http://jsfiddle.net/jackrugile/SkhqF/

It changes the duration based on whether the ul is being hovered over or not, and applies a small setTimeout to handle the animation when leaving the ul. Thanks to @GregL's answer for inspiration.

Comment: hmmm... nothing appear now. I'm dissecting it. But what you say makes sense.

Comment: Yeah, you will have to tweak your css for the .js-subitems to show properly. Let me know if you need any help with that.

Comment: Oh I got it... each submenu is INSIDE of a li item. That works! HOWEVER:

I can't have any animation showing that there are multiple sub menu divs. It should act like it did before. See the site now with your changes:

http://www.bridgecitymedical.com/

There are a ton of divs sliding around. How can I prevent that slide up animation when going form tab-to-tab under your version, but let it remain when you hove out of the whole menu?

Thanks dude!

Comment: I think I see what you mean now, each menu item will have a different list underneath it, but they will all essentially look like they are being stored in the same box. And you want this to only animate up and down when you are entering or leaving the entire navigation in general, not when moving from item to item, does that sound correct?

Comment: Yepp. That's right. You're changes were AWESOME and solved my problem. But they created another one. How can I prevent that animation from tab-to-tab so it looks like it did prior to your edit, but functions like it does now.

;)

Comment: @JacksonGariety I would consider adding a 'hover' or 'active' class in the first callback in `.hover()` to the `<li>`, and removing it in the second callback. Then, before the `.slideUp()` line, check if there are any `<li>`s with that class. If so, don't slide down... Does that get you on the right track?

Comment: Ok, I think the easiest way to do it, is to move one div out of the list like you had before, and that will act as your subitem background that slides up and down. Bind the hover event to #js-menu to trigger the sliding up and down of the background div. This will prevent the multiple firing. Then, keep your actual subitem content where they are now(in the li), and remove the large background, leaving them as only text elements. Then you could choose to fade them in and out instead of slide, or whatever you want. Let me know if that makes sense, I could make a demo.

Comment: Yes. But how do I "check if there are any lists and don't slide down"

Comment: Yeah, I don't particularly want to go that rout because the way I'm going to be presenting the content of those divs, they should actually be nested inside of the sub-items element.

I was thinking, is there any way we can create a variable like this: var $speed = 200, then change that speed based on what tab we're going from/to. So if we go from no tab to one tab, it $speed = 200, if we go from tab-to-tab, $speed = 0, so we won't get that animation. If that's possible, I would much prefer that. How can that be accomplished?

*thanks for help btw*

Answer (score 1):

Here is my completely untested tweak to @jackrugile's javascript. If nothing else, it might give you some ideas. The order of the statements might need fixing.

**EDIT:** New approach: set the active state on the containing `<nav>` element instead. Code updated.

**EDIT 2:** Newer approach: check if there is already another submenu expanded, and if so, skip the animation. Removed the `<nav>` class idea, I don't think it would allow any animations.

```
$('#js-menu li').hover(function(){
    $(this).find('.js-tab').css('background-color', 'black').css('color', 'white').children('.js-icon').css('background-position', '0px -65px');
    var duration = 150;
    if ($('.js-subitems:visible').length) // if another tab active then show it immediately
        duration = 0;
    $(this).find('.js-subitems').slideDown(duration);
},function(){
    $(this).find('.js-tab').css('background-color', 'white').css('color', 'black').children('.js-icon').css('background-position', '0 0');
    var duration = 200;
    if ($('.js-subitems:visible').length) // if another tab active then hide it immediately
        duration = 0;
    $(this).find('.js-subitems').slideUp(duration);
});
```

Comment: Btw, totally not trying to steal @jackrugile's thunder. Accept his answer if that was the main thing that worked, I just wanted to throw an idea out there that can be upvoted if helpful.

Comment: Thx for not repuation-whoring dude! I'll check it out now.

Comment: Also, read my most recent comment on @jackrugile 's post, it explains what I'm trying to accomplish now.

Comment: Yeah, see with yours I run into the same problem I had with jack's.

Comment: Yeah, I see what you're getting at now, sorry.

Comment: NICE. Still sin't working, now I'm puzzled why, it SHOULD work! :D You're onto something.

Comment: The issue lies within checking if it's active.

Comment: Yeah, I feel like in theory this should work. However, the removing of the active class is happening right before the check at `if ($('#js-menu li.active').length)`, so it will never satisfy that if statement. I a solution to this would be to set the var duration before the bind, and add the active class to the ul on hover. Duration will be 0 while on the ul, and 200 while off the ul.

Comment: @JacksonGariety @jackrugile New approach - set the `active` class on the containing `<nav>` instead (answer updated). Does that work better?

Comment: PROGRESS:

It works. Kinda. When you hover OUT of everything, the duration is still 0. Crap. Lemme think.

Comment: @JacksonGariety I realised too late that my logic would prevent any animations from happening. Updated answer again with another new approach.

Comment: You used 'visible'. Shouldn't it be 'block' since jQuery uses display:none not visibility:hidden ? Or am I wrong. Regardless, it doesn't work.

Comment: This one just brings back the duration=200 when going tab-to-tab. The only tim theres NO animation now is on the hover OUT of the menubar. LOL

Comment: I tried adding something like this:

$nav.mouseleave(function(){
 $(this).removeClass('active');
 var duration = 200;
});

So when you left the whole menubar it would reset the duration and class.

Comment: Just updated my answer with a jsFiddle demo, let me know if that works. Based on some of @GregL's logic.

Comment: @jackrugile Your way is pretty buggy, at least with my setup. http://www.bridgecitymedical.com/ If you move to quickly, the submenu gets stuck down. And there's this slight jittering between each tab.

Comment: The jitter was from a '10' you had in there, should've been a 0.

Comment: Thanks mate, I moved a few things around and it's PERFECT.

Comment: @jackrugile It's the closest either of us has got. There are small flaws with it (moving the mouse off the element and back on quickly, for instance), but for most purposes, I'd be happy with that.

Comment: @JacksonGariety I gather you don't care about IE6? It looks awful in IE6 thanks to lack of transparent PNG support.

Comment: Yeah, I had to add the `.stop(false,true)` because for some reason with sliding in jQuery, things get stuck so easily. But it needed at least some sort of `.stop()` to prevent animation queueing. I never have that problem with show/hide or fading. Glad you at least got closer! Off to bed ;)

Comment: @GregL Yeah, I still have IE6 bug-testing to do. (nightmare) But I'm far better with CSS then I am with javascript, AND and I'm getting rid of those png's and getting jpgs instead. The png's were for the old menubar that I got rid of.